# How to place a button in specific place that doesnt take up a line

Tags: html, css, button

I have this code: http://pastebin.com/M2GravSL

I am trying to add a button in the middle of the page, across from "input B", but it makes a wide hole in-between the "A-input" and "B-input" text. Is there a way to fix this so that the button does not take up a line and is just independent? I would like this to be done I HTML or CSS. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use jsfiddle. Pastebin is meh.
2. Learn position: relative vs absolute.

   ```
     <form name=apple style='position:relative'>

    <input style='position:absolute;right:0px;top:50px' class="button" type=button value="Shoot" onClick="main();">
   ```

Generally, the parent should have position: relative (in this case the form), and the child should have position: absolute so his "top" starts from the parent.

Here's a jsfiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/ghnz0e2m/

Please mark my answer correct by hitting the checkmark if I have helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. jsfiddle.net is much cleaner, thanks for the tip.